# How to test if every element in a numpy array is masked

Tags: python, numpy

How do I test if every element in a numpy array is masked?  Here's what I'd like to do:

```
x = #is a maksed numpy array
masked_min = numpy.ma.min(x)
if masked_min IS NOT A MASKED ELEMENT:
  #do some stuff only if masked_min is a value
```

In practice I see this:

```
>>> x = numpy.ma.array(numpy.array([1,2,3]),mask=[True,True,True])
>>> masked_min = numpy.ma.min(x)
masked
```

Testing for `masked` is not helpful:

```
>>> numpy.ma.sum(x) == numpy.ma.masked
masked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most Pythonic way would be to just do what you want, and then catch any errors that result if the entire array is masked.

For example:

```
x = numpy.ma.array(numpy.array([1,2,3]),mask=[True,True,True])
try: 
    my_min = numpy.min(x[~x.mask])
    # Continue with my_min
except ValueError: 
    # Bail or what have you
    print 'Masks all around!'
```

Comment: @DSM, I don't understand your comment.  Here ~x.mask is used as an index into x, but if all False yields an empty array to `numpy.min` which throws an Exception.  Isn't that okay?

Comment: Ah, that's just my inability to read -- my eyes passed right over the `[~x.mask]`.

Comment: The problem with this "better sorry than safe" kind of approach, is that if your code ends up throwing a ValueError for a totally different reason than what you expect, you'll still catch it and it will be silent… better test with .mask.all() like the other answer does (though this is more pythonic)

Answer (score 20):

If by "test if an entire array is masked in numpy" you mean whether every element is masked, since the mask itself an array, you could use `.mask.all()`:

```
>>> x = numpy.ma.array(numpy.array([1,2,3]),mask=[True,True,True])
>>> x
masked_array(data = [-- -- --],
             mask = [ True  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> x.mask
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> x.mask.all()
True
```

or maybe `.count()`, but that's axis-dependent.  OTOH if you really only need to test whether the result of your min call is "masked", you can do that directly:

```
>>> numpy.ma.min(x)
masked
>>> type(_)
<class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant'>
>>> isinstance(numpy.ma.min(x), numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant)
True
>>> numpy.ma.min(x) is numpy.ma.masked
True
```

[There might be easier ways to do this; I seldom use masked arrays myself.]

Comment: Yes, I meant "whether every element is masked", I've changed the title of my question.